# How can we syncing UI Avatar with the NLP responses?

Tags: user-interface, nlp, openai-api, avatar

I want to syncing our UI Avatar with our NLP responses which is generated by using Open AI API key. in which I am giving the text input as just like query and getting the proper responses of that query with the help of Open AI API key.and I want to give this responses to the UI Avatar for to fullfil our requirements.